# Permission denied when it shouldn't be

Tags: permissions

```
root@photon-machine [ /mnt/data/torrents ]# touch aa
touch: cannot touch 'aa': Permission denied
root@photon-machine [ /mnt/data/torrents ]# ls -al
total 131
drwxrwxr-x  5 1000 nasgroup  5 Aug 26 21:03 .
drwxrwxr-x 23 1000 nasgroup 26 Aug 26 22:51 ..
drwxrwxr-x 12 1000 nasgroup 13 Aug 27 14:11 complete
drwxrwxr-x  2 1000 nasgroup  2 Aug 27 14:11 incomplete
drwxrwxr-x  2 1000 nasgroup  9 Aug 27 11:11 torrents_watched_folder
root@photon-machine [ /mnt/data/torrents ]# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1000(nasgroup)
```

According to the above I should be able to create a file in that directory.

What am I missing?

Does it matter that the **/mnt/data** is a **nfs** (version 3) mount from a TrueNas box?

the line in **/etc/fstab** is the following:

```
192.168.1.50:/mnt/NasPool/main/Transmission   /mnt/data   nfs   defaults   0   0
```

To answer the questions:
@user10489:
in **/etc/exports** the line looks like:

```
/mnt/NasPool/main/Transmission -alldirs -quiet
```

If I touch a file in a 777 permissions directory, I get

```
-rw-r----- 1 nobody nasgroup 0 Aug 27 16:09 aa
```

@telometto:
if I do a **ls -l** on my dirs from the TrueNas box I get:

```
drwxrwxr-x   2 acasa  acasa   9 Aug 27 11:11 torrents_watched_folder
```

and the same permissions for the other 2 folders.
if I issue **id acasa**, I get the following:

```
uid=1000(acasa) gid=1000(acasa) groups=1000(acasa)
```

Comment: What does the export line from the NAS look like?  is rootsquash enabled or disabled?  If you have a directory with permissions 0777 and touch a file in it, who owns the file?

Comment: If you SSH into your NAS, what's the output of `ls -l` of the `torrents` dir and its subdirs (who's the owner and group)?

Comment: I edited the post because of limited formatting options in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NFS protocol, to reduce security issues, "squashes" the root userid to the user `nobody` unless the `no_root_squash` option is used.  (Default is `root_squash`.)

The solution here is either to enable this option (dangerous!  If you do, at least restrict it by host.) or stop using root to access this NFS share and switch to a regular user.

(Note: some versions of NFS may spell this option differently.)

Comment: I would like to say that for the **TrueNasCore** (at least) modifying directly the **/etc/exports** file is not a good option, as the file gets overwritten each time the machine boots. For persistence of settings across reboots is better to use the web interface to change settings.

Comment: I wouldn't change the option anyway.  It's best to just not use root to access NFS.